# Change badge criteria according to overall site activity

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

It's generally known that different sites have different traffic and user activity. But criteria for badges still remain the same. That's definitely making some badges differ in difficulty in obtaining on different sites. For example, on a (relatively) less active site, Tumbleweed is easier to obtain, whereas Epic and Legendary are nearly impossible.
Due to this, I think it's good to change the badge criteria so that the actual number varies by site, making same badge on different sites have similar difficulty to obtain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm currently working my way towards an epic and legendary badge (and at this point it's impossible for me to get unsung hero) - and frankly, repcaps (for those two badges) has nothing to do with overall site activity. It's all about either grinding a few questions a day with some upvotes (which is how my early reputation was), bounties or HNQs. It's worth remembering those posts are designed to be a *long term* thing (I'm a little over a halfway through for my epic, almost 8 years on) as an incentive for users who're basically in for the long haul *or* are early users

SU's the only site I have access to analytics for, and these analytics are fine to share as far as I know -

[image]

And well, post counts, votes and traffic seem... entirely unrelated. They also tend to occasionally randomly drop and go back up, sometimes suddenly.

So essentially if we base it off post count, it's going to vary. If we base it off any other metric, an early badge is easier to get (cause of early interest in a site) than a badge later on, but if a site grows, it's easier.

In a practical sense, rather than normalising the "value" of a badge across sites, it muddles the value of it in time. If it's harder for me to get a badge in say, SF or SU, that's fine. It has more value to me then.

Comment: I think your very last phrase deserves way more ***value***, why not put it in bold?

Comment: The badge not the phrase. Also people don't like formatting here

Comment: If formatting is not liked around here, then how about making it a separated part of your answer (a kind of 2nd answer in this very same answer?

Comment: "at this point it's impossible for me to get tumbleweed" why? There have been 16 awarded on SU in the last 2 days :)

Comment: hm. I think I confused that with unsung hero.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree it is harder to get certain badges on low traffic sites and that it is "not fair", I don't think we need a dynamic badge criteria for the following reasons:

- It would cause lots of confusion for existing users who have accounts on several sites.
- It would be very complex, requiring lots of development time, that is better spent elsewhere.
- Such a change will probably require "badge recalculation", which will cause lots of users to lose existing badges, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Well, [a regular badge is never lost](/a/17854/350567). Also there is no need for *real* dynamic, I think we can simply categorize sites into three classes, "High Activity", "Med Act" and "Low Act" and set criteria correspondingly.

Comment: @iBug I agree with this answer and I think you underestimate the complexity and the development time involved—especially the development time required for *ongoing maintenance.*